# Can a variable $X$ represent a different value on each side of an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Is it possible that under certain conditions, the value of $X$ in the following equation is different on each side such that by eliminating it the value of the two sides are no longer equal?

$$(a+b) - X = (p+q) - X$$

$$(a+b) \neq(p+q)$$

But introducing X on each side results in an equation.

Comment: No. If anyone uses the same symbol $X$ for two different things, they should be reprimanded.

Comment: No there is almost no case I can think of where this works.  Also how would you go about eliminating $X$ from both sides? I see no way to do this unless they are the same $X$

Comment: If $a,b,p,q,X$ are numbers with usual addition and subtraction, this is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Whenever you use any symbol, it should be clearly stated what that symbol represents and it should refer to one object only. It might be fixed number, or it may be some variable, but it can't change meaning before you are done with whatever you are trying to do.

If you want to write something similar to allow different values on each side, use a different alphabet letter, like $Y$:

$$(a+b) - X = (p+q) - Y.$$

It might be that $X\neq Y$, but it's not necessary. Different letters don't exclude possibility $X = Y$. However, $X = X$, no flexibility here.